# Is there a BibTeX package for referencing other records within the BibTeX file? Displaying this?

Tags: bibtex

I want to understand the relationships between a set of papers in a bibtex file, with regards to who authored what, and which references which, within the file.

Suppose the paper `\cite{A}` references `\cite{B}`, and both of them reference `\cite{C}`.

I want a BibTeX file that has this information, say like this:

```
@incollection{A,
    Author = {Mr A},
    Booktitle = {A Book},
    Title = {Title of A},
    Year = {2010},
    Internalrefs = {B,C}
}

@incollection{B,
    Author = {Mr B},
    Booktitle = {B Book},
    Title = {Title of B},
    Year = {2009},
    Internalrefs = {C}
}

@incollection{C,
    Author = {Mr C},
    Booktitle = {C Book},
    Title = {Title of C},
    Year = {1910},
    Internalrefs = {}
}
```

With that entry I could, for example, draw a directed graph of entries within the BibTeX file.  I suppose I can do this with a custom field, but I wondered if it has been done, or if there is a better way.

I'd like to display for example

```
Metadata for paper A.  [B,C]
Metadata for paper B. [C]
Metadata for paper C.
```

Or alternatively just a graph with directed edges (A,B), (A,C), and possibly nodes for authors too, pointing to the papers they have published, and other authors they published with.

Comment: `biblatex` has a facility to have related references. can you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added an example at the end, and the purpose at the beginning of the post.

Comment: `biber` (which requires the use of `biblatex`, can 'visualize the output' using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org); is that what you mean?

Comment: biber seems to offer a cross referencing tool, but it is so that one entry can inherit from another.  That is not what I want because it will change my bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

The BibTeX "crossref" field does what you want. For an example (I've stripped some irrelevant information):

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/atva/EsikFLQ13,
title     = {Kleene Algebras and Semimodules for Energy Problems},
crossref  = {DBLP:conf/atva/2013}
}

@proceedings{DBLP:conf/atva/2013,
title     = {Automated Technology for Verification and Analysis - 11th
           International Symposium, ATVA 2013, Hanoi, Vietnam, October
           15-18, 2013. Proceedings},
booktitle = {ATVA},
publisher = {Springer}
}
```

Now for a tool which uses crossrefs to extract a directed citation graph; this would certainly be cool, but I've never ran across any.

Comment: I'm close to creating one by making a special template for Bibdesk that exports the citations to a Sage software Digraph().  Perhaps I'll check back when that is done.

Comment: With the changes you made to the question, my answer is now wrong: "crossref" does not do what you want. (You almost say so yourself at your last comment to the question.)